# Converting CSV file to set then list for unique list but getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert the CSV file list to set to get the unique results but I am getting the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error. How to overcome this problem and get only the unique list?

```
import csv

with open('f.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    unique_list = csv.reader(csv_file)
    print(list(set(unique_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make them tuples:

```
   print(list(set(map(tuple, unique_list))))
```